# Returning a vector<object>

Tags: c++, vector

I searched over the net how to return a vector object but I can't find the simplest one. First of all, I am not expert in C++ and I just started C++ few weeks ago. Is it not okay to return an object vector?

I have something like this.

I pushed it somewhere through this:

MAIN File:

```
int main()
{   
    XIniFile *f = new XIniFile();
    int result = 0;

    int v = 0;
    char *val;

    result = f->open("doc2.ini");

    if (INI_FILE_RES_OK == result) {
    }

    else
        printf("Error[%d]\n", result);
}
```

CPP File:

```
XKey::XKey()
{
}

XKey::~XKey()
{
}

XSection::XSection()
{
}

XSection::~XSection()
{
}

XKey *XSection::addKey(const char *k, const char *val)
{
    XKey *nk = new XKey;
    nk->setName(k);
    nk->setValue(val);
    m_vkey.push_back(*nk);
    return nk;
}

void XSection::showKey()
{
    vector<XKey>::iterator ik;
    for (ik = m_vkey.begin(); ik != m_vkey.end(); ik++)
        printf("%s = %s\n", ik->getName(), ik->getValue());
}

XIniFile::XIniFile()
{
    m_modified = false;
}

int XIniFile::open(const char *fn)
{   
    XSection *cs;

    char *sn;
    char *kn;
    char *val;
    int i = 0;

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(fn, "r");

    if (!f)
        return INI_FILE_ERROR;

    struct stat file_stat;
    stat(fn, &file_stat);
    int size = file_stat.st_size;

    m_name = strdup(fn);

    char *d = (char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char *) + 1);

    fread(d, size, 1, f);

    while (i < size) {
        while (d[i] != '[') i++;

        if (d[i] == '[') {
            i++;

            while (isspace(d[i])) i++;

            sn = &d[i];
            while (d[i] != ']')
                i++;
            d[i++] = 0;

            cs = addSection(sn);

            while (isspace(d[++i]));

            while(d[i] != '[') {

                while (isspace(d[i])) i++;

                kn = &d[i];
                while (d[i] != '=') i++;
                d[i-1] = 0;
                i++;

                while (isspace(d[i])) i++;

                if (d[i] == '[') {
                    i++;
                    val = &d[i];
                    while (isspace(d[i])) i++;
                    d[i-1] = 0;
                }

                else {
                    val = &d[i];
                    while (d[i] != '\n') i++;
                    d[i] = 0;
                }
                i++;

                cs->addKey(kn, val);

                while (isspace(d[i])) {
                    i++;
                    if (i >= size) break;
                }

                if (i >= size) break;
            }
        }
    }    
    free(d);

    vector<XSection>::iterator is;

    for (is = m_vsection.begin(); is != m_vsection.end(); is++) {
        printf("[%s]\n", is->getName());
        printf("is->getSize()[%d]\n", is->getSize());
    }

    fclose(f);
    return INI_FILE_RES_OK;
}

XIniFile::~XIniFile()
{
    delete m_name;   
}

XSection *XIniFile::addSection(const char *s)
{
    XSection *ns = new XSection;
    ns->setName(s);
    m_vsection.push_back(*ns);

    return ns;
}

void XIniFile::showSection()
{
    vector<XSection>::iterator is;
    for (is = m_vsection.begin(); is != m_vsection.end(); is++)
        printf("[%s]\n", is->getName());
    printf("End\n");
}
```

Header File:

```
class XKey
{   
public:
    XKey();
    virtual ~XKey();

    void *setName(const char *k) {m_name = strdup(k);}
    void *setValue(const char *v) {m_value = strdup(v);}
    char *getName(){return m_name;}
    char *getValue(){return m_value;}

private:
    char *m_name;
    char *m_value;
};

class XSection
{   
public:
    XSection();
    virtual ~XSection();  

    void *setName(const char *n) {m_name = strdup(n);}
    char *getName() {return m_name;}
    XKey *addKey(const char *k, const char *v);
    vector<XKey> getKey() {return m_vkey;}
    int getSize() {return m_vkey.size();}
    void showKey();

private:    
    char *m_name;
    vector<XKey> m_vkey;
};

class XIniFile
{
public:
    XIniFile();
    virtual ~XIniFile();

    int open(const char *);
    int readString(const char *, const char *, char **);
    int readInt(const char *, const char *, int *);
    XSection *addSection(const char *);
    void showSection();

private:
    char *m_name;
    vector<XSection> m_vsection;
    bool m_modified;
};
```

the problem here is that under CPP file `is->getSize()` doesn't increase even if I used `push_back` on `m_vkey` which could be found on my `addKey` method.

Comment: Could you show code that actually compiles?

Comment: You should also show us the offending test case code.

Comment: Your `XSection` class will be copied, and that operation is dangerous for you because of all the raw pointers.  Use `std::string` instead, and it may "just work".

Comment: @Chad can you tell me which part of my code `XSection` gets copied?

Comment: You store both XSection and XKey in vectors and both have raw pointers.  `push_back` can make a copy of that element, and any resizing of the vector could cause all of the elements to be copied to the new storage.  It's unclear why you allocate an item with new and then immediately push it into a vector.  Your code has tons of memory leaks.  Perhaps the only reason it isn't crashing all over the place is that you don't delete anything.

Comment: There is a pointer "char *m_name" in XSection, and you don't have a copy constructor for it .When you assign a instance of XSection to another  , and so on, Value-Copy will happen .So "m_name" of two  instances of XSection will point to the same address. It's dangrous. And you should print something before you use push_back , just to make sure.log is very helpful for you to debug your code .I think you'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the object you're modifying is not the same as the one you're storing.

Look here:

```
XSection *XIniFile::addSection(const char *s)
{
    XSection *ns = new XSection;   // Create a new XSection
    ns->setName(s);
    m_vsection.push_back(*ns);     // Store a copy of ns

    return ns;                     // Return the original ns
}
```

Now when you do something with the return value, the object in `m_vsection` is unaffected.

The quickest fix is to store the pointers you're returning in m_vsection instead, and similar for the section objects.
Although you should probably start using `std::shared_ptr` (not to mention `std::string`) if at all possible.